# How to disable process explorer on windows XP

Tags: windows

How to disable [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) on Windows XP?

I have an internet cafe and some clients use this to stop the minutes on tinasoft(EASYCAFE)

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Are you suggesting that your Task Manager has been replaced with Process Explorer??

Comment: Then do not use it.

Comment: It is a standalone application. It doesn't install itself. So you may as well delete the EXE without causing any problems if you do not want to use it...

Comment: Also, this suggests to me that they may be running as administrator users, it would definitely worth making sure they run as standard users.

Answer (score 4):

1. Click **Options**
2. Uncheck **Replace Task Manager**.

[image]

Comment: Delete the exe of the application would be easy one, then in future you will never launch it. Also you can put its exe somewhere else where you don't access it soon.

Answer (score 4):

I might consider installing the tinasoft(EASYCAFE) application as an administrator.

Then giving clients that access your computers at the cafe, a guest login with limited privileges. They should not be able to make changes to the process running on the computer with out have having administrator privileges.

I would also log a support request from tinasoft and ask them how to prevent this type of behaviour. If the time management software is so easily subverted, it is a bug / flaw in the software they sold you and should provide you with a fix.